# Python opencv external camera live stream

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing, camera

I tried to open live stream with opencv in python with an external camera(ESP32). The code that I am using is working when I write cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0) and gives me the live stream with the laptop's camera. The camera(ESP32) itself is working when I write the IP of it on the web and gives me the live stream. But, when I try to connect the python code and the camera together it gives me an empty frame error. This is the code I was using.

```
import cv2
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.222.17/")
while(True):
    ret, frame = cap.read()
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)
    if cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF == ord('q'):
        cap.release()
        cv2.destroyAllWindows()
        break
```

I also tried cv2.VideoCapture(1), cv2.VideoCapture(-1), cv2.VideoCapture(2) ,cv2.VideoCapture(4), cv2.VideoCapture("http://192.168.222.17:80/video") and dev method but none of them was working.
This is the error it gave:

```
 line 12, in <module>
    cv2.imshow('frame',frame)

error: OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\color.cpp:182: error: (-215:Assertion failed) !_src.empty() in function 'cv::cvtColor'



[ERROR:0@5.028] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (166) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): http://192.168.222.17/ in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'


[ WARN:0@1632.150] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_msmf.cpp (539) `anonymous-namespace'::SourceReaderCB::~SourceReaderCB terminating async callback
[ERROR:0@3077.803] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (166) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): http://192.168.222.17/ in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'


[ERROR:0@4202.231] global D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap.cpp (166) cv::VideoCapture::open VIDEOIO(CV_IMAGES): raised OpenCV exception:

OpenCV(4.5.5) D:\a\opencv-python\opencv-python\opencv\modules\videoio\src\cap_images.cpp:253: error: (-5:Bad argument) CAP_IMAGES: can't find starting number (in the name of file): http://192.168.222.17/ in function 'cv::icvExtractPattern'
```

Can you please help me fix this problem?

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm trying to solve the same issue. I suspect it has to do with how Sony streams packets of data, rather than a clean video feed. I'm not sure how to handle it though.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to connect to it's rtsp port (554):

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://192.168.222.17/")
```

And if there are credentials, you need to enter them:

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture("rtsp://user:pass@192.168.222.17/")
```

Comment: Thank you so much for the explanation. I tried these two codes too(My camera doesn't have password and user) so I tried rtsp://192.168.222.17/ but it gave me the same error. Should I change anything in writing rtsp related to my camera and code?

Comment: Are you sure that your ip camera supports rtsp streams? You can read the datasheet of your camera for more details.